# #Wagmi: TypeError: x.replace is not a function after migration from 0.X to 1.X.X

Tags: web3js, wagmi, view

Same code I didn't change a thing. Only a few things in wagconfig to make the migration but the rest should work.
I have this error using:

```js
const { config, error } = usePrepareContractWrite({...data})
```

error:
`TypeError: x.replace is not a function at eval (webpack-internal:///(:3080/app-client)/./node_modules/.pnpm/viem@1.7.0_typescript@5.0.4/node_modules/viem/dist/esm/utils/data/concat.js:26:51) at Array.reduce (<anonymous>) at concatHex (webpack-internal:....)`

Comment: Changing view dep from view 1.x.x to "viem": "~0.3.36"
Solves the issue but this needs further research